# Kapacitor: How to get Field name in TICK script

Tags: kapacitor

I'm trying to create a TICK script via Chronograf and it works nicely.
I have some tags set and some fields.
I created an Alert tick file for specific field and I can get its value by doing

```
{{ index .Fields "value" }}
```

but I can't get its name...is that even possible?

Thank you!

Comment: Well, the name of the field is "value" isn't it? So you already kind of have it. Or I don't understand your question.

Comment: I just interested to get it programatically

Comment: Oh, I guess I got you. So you have some datapoints, but don't have names of fields in them? Then I guess I could answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fields is a map from string to interface ([see source](https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/blob/master/models/point.go#L44)). So you could iterate over that mapping using following template:

```
{{ range $key, $value := .Fields}}
    Arbitrary text here, but you could for example show all fields
    in the form {{$key}}={{$value}}
{{end}}
```

Comment: That's interesting!

Comment: by the way, is there a way to add field name and value to the output json alert but not part as "message", but rather as part of `data` ?

Comment: @Shvalb Don't know, need to figure it out. But community for Kapacitor is very small here on StackOverflow, probably most questions are discussed on on their forum.

Comment: Thank you for your help!